# font.draw() works correctly on first call but not on second

Tags: libgdx

I'm not sure if you're not allowed to call font.draw() twice but the first linedisplays correctly but the second one is very glitchy, a lot of letters are missing [that appear fine in the first line] and random numbers seem to not draw. My .fnt file is fine as it works on buttons and checkbox's just fine.

Here's some of my code:

```
private BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("test.fnt"),false);
private SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
//in Render Method

    batch.begin();

    font.draw(batch, "Best Distance: " + bestDistance + "m", Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2);

    font.draw(batch, "Distance: " + finalDistance + "m", Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    stage.draw();


    hud.stage.draw();


    batch.end();
```

If I switch the order of their draw call then whichever one is called first draws correctly.

Comment: Just as a quick update: I found if I add a third line the second one will display correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `stage.draw()` without closing the spritebatch. Simply call `batch.end()` before starting to draw the stage.
Rendering a batch inside another opened batch will result in all kind of weird behaviour that makes you think the fault lies in everything but the batch.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407935/libgdx-very-strange-bug-objects-are-disappeared) is a similar problem.