# Unable to draw a font and a stage at the same time on LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a stage and a string with a specific font, but when I draw the stage, the string disappears, but the images do not. I suppose it's  a simple thing, but I have no idea. I've already tried to change the order to render, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any help would be aprecciated.

```
@Override
public void create() {

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    textatlas = new TextureAtlas("Agorafunfa.txt");
    TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion a = textatlas.findRegion("spider");
    spider = new Sprite(a);
    img = new Texture("Captura.PNG");
    yesa = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("yesa.fnt"));
    font = "Escape Planet";
    img3 = new Texture("saturno.png");
    funciona = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("yesa.fnt"));
    starte = "Começar";
    opcoes = "Opções";
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(ta);
    final TextButton.TextButtonStyle tbs = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    tbs.font = yesa;
    tbs.checked = skin.getDrawable("comecaversao2");
    tbs.up = skin.getDrawable("comeca");
    b = new TextButton("Começar",tbs);
    b.setHeight(250);
    b.setWidth(300);
    b.setPosition(-10, 50);
    b.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(b);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img,0,0);
    batch.draw(img3, 200,170, 250, 170);
    yesa.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    yesa.draw(batch,font,430,300);
    stage.draw();//if I comment this line, the string appears
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on right track, `stage.draw()` is causing the problem. You're calling it without closing the spritebatch before. If you look into stage's source code you'll see it has its own spritebatch. Call `batch.end()` before drawing the stage.

Rendering a batch inside another opened batch will result in all kind of weird behaviour that makes you think the fault lies in everything but the batch.

---

As these type of problems pop up frequently nowadays I checked out the [stage docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html), there is clear information that it uses its own batch, you can even set your own with the constructor `stage(Viewport viewport, Batch batch)`. If you use that constructor you don't need to use the solution above. However the docs doesn't mention batches needs to be closed, not even in the [batch docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html). This is something that probably should be added so we can avoid the same issues popping up.

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800477/font-draw-works-correctly-on-first-call-but-not-on-second) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407935/libgdx-very-strange-bug-objects-are-disappeared).